# kafka streams for conversion of JSON arrays to json objects

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a code in normal java for converting JSON arrays to JSON objects and i need to convert this normal java to kafka streams...below is my

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
public class JsonParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("/root/jsonTestFile.json"));
             for (Object o : jsonArray) {
//to get the Json object
              JSONObject snap = (JSONObject) o;
              System.out.println(snap);
             }
}
 catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If someone help me in writing code for only logic part i can coninue with that, below is my logic part atleast i need help for this

```
public class JsonParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("/root/jsonTestFile.json"));
             for (Object o : jsonArray) {
//to get the Json object
              JSONObject snap = (JSONObject) o;
              System.out.println(snap);
             }
}
```

How can i write the same code in kafka streams? can somebody help in doing this?

Comment: Need to implement serializer and deserializer, This [Link](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#data-types-and-serialization) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend two options:

- You implement your own serializer/deserializer ([Here is the javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-summary.html))
- You can process your stream as a stream of (String,String) and use a flatMap to parse each element of your stream and transform it to a stream of (String,JSONObject):

  ```
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  stringStream.flatMap((k,v) -> {
      List<KeyValue<String,JSONOBject>> tmp = new ArrayList<KeyValue<String,JSONOBject>>();
      JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(v);
      for (Object o : jsonArray) {
           JSONObject snap = (JSONObject) o;
           tmp.add(new KeyValue(k, snap));
      }     
      return tmp;
  });
  ```

Here I didn't treat at all the exception you have to wrap the code of the lambda into a try/catch.

Comment: hey can you check my above code which i have posted as answer and clear my doubts